# Cannot initialize brand new SATA hard disk drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, sata, storage

I am unable to initialize a brand new hard drive.

In Windows 10 Disk Management the HDD is listed as disk 3. I get an error that states:

```
The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.
```

I've tried two different SATA cables and two different power cables. The physical connection looks like this:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why does this hard drive hate me?

Comment: There looks to be a fair bit of strain on those cables. Power down. Extract the drive & just have it loose, so you can get the cabling dead straight. Try again. SATA cables hate being forced into place, it makes them very susceptible to data error. If you have to make any bends, make them well away from the plugs & as gentle as you can.

Comment: @Tetsujin To be fair, I tried two different cables and initially, I had the backplate off my PC so all of the pressure and strain would have been relieved. When I plug the cable into my adjacent SSD, there's no data issues what-so-ever. It's only when I plug in this HDD that it starts whining.

Comment: Sounds like it might be time to RMA the drive while you still can.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think you're right. I didn't want to accept what I already knew...

Comment: @Tetsujin Just reporting back. Got a new hard drive from Amazon in the mail and it immediately worked. Newegg definitely sent me a bad drive.

Comment: @Tetsujin I probably should have mentioned this before, but I only noticed when I plugged in the new drive; my bad hard drive was making this god awful noise on boot, like the needle was dragging on the record or something. When I plugged in my new hard drive, it went away completely. I should have known that meant I had a bad HDD.

Answer (score 0):

**If you think your hard drive is bad, steps to follow:**

1. Check connectors
2. Try different connectors
3. Try different ports on your motherboard
4. Try a different motherboard or computer
5. Try a different Operating System

If that fails, you probably have a bad hard drive.

In my case, the drive was making a horrible noise on startup. That would only happen with an HDD, but that's another tell-tale sign of failure.